# How to auto tab between Formik Field?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, formik

I have a component for 4 digit code of phone validation. By itself it works fine and looks good as well. The only issue I am facing - I can't autotab between numbers. I have to go to each input manually and write the number. Is it possible to do with Formik Field?

This is my piece of code:

```
<Formik
  onSubmit={values =>
    VerifyGarageFunc({ code: values.code.join(''), requestId: PhoneCodeData.data }, data.showModal)
  }>
  {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FieldArray
        name="code"
        render={arrayHelpers => (
          <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
            {values.code.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <Field
                  name={`code.${index}`}
                  type="text"
                  component={CustomInput}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.code[index]}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      />
      <LoginActionButton onSubmit={handleSubmit} text={'Send'} />
      <FieldArray />
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-auto-tab but it works only with `<input/>`, for some reason it doesn't work at all with Formik Field.

P.S. I am using Next.js with React.js

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have more luck with a hook based solution. Install https://github.com/Romr1ch/react-pin-input-hook, which just does the logic without being opinionated about display.

Create a new component called `PinInput` and create a new field using the formik hook primitives.

Ive setup an example codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pin-input-hook-custom-input-1ze5dv?file=/src/App.js, but note this doesn't use your exact components as I don't have them. The below code should match closer your exact case.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useField } from 'formik'
import { usePinInput } from 'react-pin-input-hook'

export const PinInput = (props) => {
     const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props)
     const { fields } = usePinInput({
       values: field.value,
       onChange: (values) => {
         helpers.setValue(values)
       },
    })
    
    return fields.map((fieldProps, index) => 
      <CustomInput key={index} type="text" {...fieldProps} />
    )
}
```

Then in your main file do this (by the way if you use `Form` component from Formik you dont need to do any of the `onSubmit` binding yourself, so I changed that along the way -- the button can just be "submit" type):

```
<Formik
  onSubmit={values =>
    VerifyGarageFunc({ code: values.code.join(''), requestId: PhoneCodeData.data }, data.showModal)
  }>
     <Form>
        <PinInput name="code" />
        <LoginActionButton type="submit" text={'Send'} />
     </Form>
</Formik>
```

Note that this lib requires your `CustomComponent` to attach a ref to the underlying thing that needs focusing so you'll need to use `forwardRef` on that component and attach it to the underlying input. It also needs to support `onBlur`, `onFocus`, `onChange` and `onKeyDown`.